# Access VBA: control for editing html code?

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, ide

I have a Access table with records containg a lot of html code pieces. I want to create a form control to edit a retrieved piece of html codes. I know the Text Box control can be used for the job.

But **I hope the Text Box control would color the html tags as in VSCode to make the editing job less painful**. No control seems to be available for this.

What can I do to creat such a primitive IDE box in Access forms? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little HTML syntax highlighter for Microsoft Access TextBoxes with the `Text Format` property set to `Rich Text` (it effectively uses HTML tags to format the text despite the name Rich Text). It is also advisable to set the `Enter Key Behavior` to `New Line in Field` for a better editing experience.

My code uses a `RegExp` object from the `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` DLL. Therefore you must set a reference to it in the VBA Editor.

Create a text `Changed` handler for your TextBox. My TextBox is named `Text1`, therefore the Sub is named `Text1_Change`. Replace it by `<your textbox name>_Change`:

```vb
Private Sub Text1_Change()
    Dim r As New RegExp
    Dim colMatches As MatchCollection
    Dim objMatch As Match
    Dim oldPos As Long, oldLen As Long, i As Long, pos As Long, l2 As Long
    Dim s As String, s1 As String, s2 As String, s3 As String, special As String
    Dim specialOffset As Long
    
    s = Replace(PlainText(Text1.Text), " ", "&nbsp;")
    With r
        .Pattern = "<[?!]?[^>/]+/?>|</\w+>"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = False
        Set colMatches = .Execute(s)
    End With
    oldPos = Text1.SelStart
    oldLen = Text1.SelLength
    For i = colMatches.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Set objMatch = colMatches(i)
        special = Mid$(objMatch.Value, 2, 1)
        specialOffset = IIf(special = "/" Or special = "?" Or special = "!", 1, 0)
        If specialOffset = 0 Then
            special = ""
        End If
        s1 = Left$(s, objMatch.FirstIndex) & "<font color=blue>&lt;" & special & "</font><font color=brown>"
        s2 = EscapeHtml(Mid$(objMatch.Value, 2 + specialOffset))
        l2 = IIf(Mid$(s2, Len(s2) - 4, 1) = "/", 5, 4)
        pos = InStr(s2, "&nbsp;")
        If pos > 0 Then
            s2 = Left$(s2, pos + 5) & "</font><font color=red>" & Mid$(s2, pos + 6, Len(s2) - pos - l2 - 5) & "</font><font color=blue>" & Right$(s2, l2)
        Else
            s2 = Left$(s2, Len(s2) - l2) & "</font><font color=blue>" & Right$(s2, l2)
        End If
        s3 = "</font>" & Mid$(s, objMatch.FirstIndex + objMatch.Length + 1)
        s = s1 & s2 & s3
    Next
    s = Replace(s, vbCrLf, "<br />")
    Text1.Text = s
    Text1.SelStart = oldPos
    Text1.SelLength = oldLen
End Sub

Private Function EscapeHtml(ByVal s As String) As String
    EscapeHtml = Replace(Replace(s, "<", "&lt;"), ">", "&gt;")
End Function
```

Don't forget the helper Function `EscapeHtml`.

The result looks like this:

[image]

Not perfect, but you are welcome to improve it.

You can retrieve the plain, unformatted text like this (`PlainText` is a built in function)

```vb
s = PlainText(Text1.Text)
```

Comment: Hi @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, Tons of thanks for sharing the complete solution! Let me try it!

Comment: I just created it now to be able to answer your question.

Comment: Hi @Olivier Jacot-Descombes, dear Sir, it works perfectly. I'm sorry for being unable to cast vote for it because of lack of reputation.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I made a form with a webbrowser control and a big textbox next to eachother bound to a table with the html in a textfield. The form loads the html text in the text field, where you can edit it and load it in the browser to show the result. You can also set EditOn = true and you can change the html in the browser itself, you have to write code if you want to save the changes made in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does your editing box color the html tags just as in VSCode?